# Kotlin equivalent for accessing inherited static constant

Tags: kotlin

In Java, if we have some abstract base class with static constant

```
abstract class BaseClass{
   public static final String BASE_CONSTANT = "BASE_CONSTANT"
}
```

Then we can call from its child class `BaseClassIml.BASE_CONSTANT`

Companion objects are not inherited, so how to do it in Kotlin?

Comment: You can always access a constant like this `BaseClass.BASE_CONSTANT`. Why do you need a tricky way to do it?

Comment: In Android you can use `View.VISIBLE`  or `ViewGroup.VISIBLE`, but you know that that `ViewGroup` extends `View`, what about classes that you don't know their parent? isn't it more intuitive to find the flag in the class you working with?

Comment: The only reason why you can access constants from the parent class is that you know what is the parent class. I think it's an excess functionality in Java and it creates implicit API which is not great. You may find this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/51796580/2314529

Comment: This sort of usage in Java is discouraged to begin with. In Kotlin, it's unsafe because child and parent can have different companion objects with differing inheritance and that have members with the same signatures.